# Alternative to SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct, sql

I'm not too familiar with SQL queries but have noticed a significant performance decrease when running a query using Select Distinct. I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2. Below is my query:

```
select distinct CL.ClientID, NL.Name 
from CL CL 
inner join PR PR on CL.ClientID = PR.ClientID 
where PR.WBT1 in (Select distinct WBT1 
                  from TabFields 
                  where custInclude = 'Y' and WBT2 = '') 
and PR.WBT2 = '' 
order by NL.Name
```

Does anyone know how to revise this query without using select distinct in order to speed up the query while returning the same results? Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: When you say "a significant performance decrease", can you provide any numbers? (how are you measuring? are you looking at query plan, query execution stats, time taken?) What is the difference between your queries? Just the "distinct" keyword in the first select clause? or also in the "IN" subquery?

Comment: You dont need the `distinct` when you use it with `IN`

Answer (score 7):

You only need DISTINCT because of the JOIN.

So don't use a JOIN: use EXISTS and push all tables that you don't actually SELECT from into the EXISTS clause

```
select CL.ClientID, CL.Name 
from CL CL 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
   FROM
      PR PR 
      JOIN
      TabFields TF ON PR.WBT1 = TF.WBT1
   WHERE
      PR.WBT2 = '' AND
      TF.custInclude = 'Y' and TF.WBT2 = '' AND
      CL.ClientID = PR.ClientID
      )
order by CL.Name
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 6):

You definitely don't need the second `SELECT DISTINCT`. You can replace it by `EXIST`:

```
select distinct CL.ClientID, NL.Name from CL CL 
inner join PR PR on CL.ClientID = PR.ClientID 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 from TabFields where WBT1=PR.WBS1 AND custInclude = 'Y' and WBT2 = '') 
and PR.WBT2 = '' order by NL.Name
```

And I don't see `NL` in `FROM /JOIN`. Did you miss it or it's supposed to be `CL`?